# Convert Vector<Point> to Mat

Tags: image-processing, opencv, vector

I try to use the function `fitLine()` from `OpenCV 2.1`, but it's needed to convert my `vector<Point>` to Mat. How can i do this?

```
 vector<Point> line_points;
 Vec4f line;
 fitLine(line_points, line, CV_DIST_L2, 0.0, 0.01, 0.01);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's actually very simple - `Mat` provides a constructor for conversion between vector of points and a `Mat`. All you need is this:

```
fitLine(Mat(line_points), line, CV_DIST_L2, 0.0, 0.01, 0.01);
```

This is mentioned [in the documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitLine).

Comment: Mat mat = Mat(line_points); Semantic Issue: Functional-style cast from 'Vector<Point>' to 'cv::Mat' is not allowed

Comment: Strange, it works in my code... Make sure you are using `std::vector<Point>`, not some kind of your own `Vector` implementation.