# How do you draw on an image from vector<CvPoints> or vector<Point2f>?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How do you draw on an image from `vector<CvPoints>` or `vector<Point2f>`?

I have VectorPoints `vector<Point2f>`. I just need to draw on an image from VectorPoints using OpenCV.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229292/convert-vectorpoint-to-mat

Comment: @BarshanDas How Vector to Mat will help / work in my case, i just to want to draw on image by taking Vector points as inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it manually:

```
Vec3b mycolor(100,0,0);
for (int i=0;i<mypoints.size();i++)
    myimage.at<Vec3b>(mypoints[i].x,mypoints[i].y)=mycolor;
```

or draw circles on those coordinates:

```
int myradius=5;
for (int i=0;i<mypoints.size();i++)
    circle(myimage,cvPoint(mypoints[i].x,mypoints[i].y),myradius,CV_RGB(100,0,0),-1,8,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just draw a polyline that connects the points in your vector, you can simply iterate through your vector elements and use the opencv line (http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) function to draw the a line between two of your points.

Answer (score 1):

Using `drawContours` after conversion from the vector of Point to vector of contours.

```
vector <vector <Point>> contours;
contours.push_back(VectorPoints);

cv::drawContours(matDraw, contours, -1, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
```