# convert vector of points to Mat (OpenCV )

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

my question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229292/convert-vectorpoint-to-mat) one... I'm trying to extract a sub matrix from a grayscale image wich is a polygon by 5 points , and convert it to a Mat.

This does not work:

```
std::vector<Point> vert(5);
vert.push_back(pt1);
vert.push_back(pt2);
vert.push_back(pt3);
vert.push_back(pt4);
vert.push_back(pt5);

Mat matROI = Mat(vert);
```

It shows me the following error message:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad number of channels (Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels) in cvConvertImage, file /home/user/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/utils.cpp, line 611
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/user/opencv-2.4.6.1/modules/highgui/src/utils.cpp:611: error: (-15) Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels in function cvConvertImage
```

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.6.1 and C++.

Thank you

**Edit:**

I will rephrase my question: my objective is to obtain the right side of the [image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/13/w0ss.png/).

I thought I'd see the image as a polygon because I have the coordinates of the vertices, and then transform the vector that has the vertices in a matrix (cvMat).

My thought is correct or is there a simpler way to get this submatrix?

Comment: What code comes after the conversion of vert to a Mat? `Mat(vert)` does not cause `cvConvertImage()` to be called.

Comment: Your edit should be a new question. I have solved the original question you asked. I.e. you are trying to display `matROI` and that is just wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has two problems:

First:

```
std::vector<Point> vert(5);
```

creates a vector initially with 5 points, so after you use `push_back()` 5 times you have a vector of 10 points, the first 5 of of which are `(0, 0)`.

Second:

```
Mat matROI = Mat(vert);
```

creates a 10x1 Mat (from a vector of 10 points) with **TWO** channels. Check that with:

```
cout << "matROI.channels()=" << matROI.channels() << endl;
```

If you have a code like:

```
imshow("Window", matROI);
```

it will pass `matROI` through to `cvConvertImage()` which has the following code (and this causes the error you are seeing):

```
if( src_cn != 1 && src_cn != 3 && src_cn != 4 )
    CV_ERROR( CV_BadNumChannels, "Source image must have 1, 3 or 4 channels" );
```

Since `matROI` is a list of points, it doesn't make sense to pass it to `imshow()`.
Instead, try this:

```
Mat img(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
polylines(img, vert, true, Scalar(255)); // or perhaps 0
imshow("Window", img);
int c = waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. In that way it just shows a small black rectangle... I said 5 points as an example, in fact I have a polygon formed by 10 points.

Comment: Rather than give a bogus example, why didn't you say what you really want? I'll change the code to work for 10 points.

Comment: I updated the answer to show why you are getting the error, and how to draw the polygon represented by `vert`

Comment: If I'm correct, the polylines function will "only" draw the polygon in the image. How can I go from there to the Mat, since polylines is a void drawing function? Should I go through the line and cols of the matrix e only include the pixels inside the polygon?

Comment: This gives me the wrong side!'vector< vector<Point> > contours;
contours.push_back(contour);
polylines(roi, contours, true, Scalar(255), CV_AA);

Mat mask = cvCreateMat(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);

     for(int i=0; i<mask.cols; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<mask.rows; j++)
            mask.at<uchar>(Point(i,j)) = img.at<uchar>(Point(i,j));

     vector<Point> ROI_Poly;

     approxPolyDP(contour, ROI_Poly, 1.0, false);

     fillConvexPoly(mask, &ROI_Poly[0], ROI_Poly.size(), 255, 8, 0);
     Mat imageDest = cvCreateMat(img.cols, img.rows, CV_8UC3);
     roi.copyTo(img, mask);'

Comment: What if you invert the mask before the copyTo? e.g. `mask = 255 - mask`.  Btw you should not call `cvCreateMat()`, as it is part of the legacy C API. Use constructor arguments instead, e.g.: `Mat mask(img.rows, img.cols, CV_8UC1);`.

Comment: I was able to get what I was looking for following this [tutorial](http://bytefish.de/blog/extracting_contours_with_opencv/), you help was also helpful @B..., thank you for your time, sorry I didnt explained myself well. Best regards